# TableViewCell's constraint returning nil on new cell creation

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, realm, interface-builder

I have a standard chat message cell that changes constraints based on the if it's the user posting the message or not.

Cell:

```
class ChatTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nonUserLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var message: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageTrailing: NSLayoutConstraint!  
}
```

Loading the data and adjusting the constraints in cellForRowAt.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.Chat.Cell, for: indexPath) as! ChatTableViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none


        let currentMessage = model?.practice?.messages[indexPath.row]
        if (currentMessage?.sender == model?.user) {
            cell.nonUserLabel.isHidden = true
            cell.userLabel.isHidden = false
            cell.messageLeading.isActive = false
            cell.messageTrailing.isActive = true
            cell.userLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "\((currentMessage?.sender?.name)!)", attributes:
            [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue])
        } else {
            cell.nonUserLabel.isHidden = false
            cell.userLabel.isHidden = true
            cell.messageLeading.isActive = true
            cell.messageTrailing.isActive = false
            cell.nonUserLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "\((currentMessage?.sender?.name)!)", attributes:
            [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue])
        }
        cell.message.text = currentMessage?.content


        return cell
    }
```

Standard stuff. This all works.

What's weird is that when I add new data to my realm database and then reload the data with tableView.reloadData(), the LABELS load fine, but the CONSTRAINTS return nil!

```
@IBAction func sendButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if textField.text! != "" {
            let message = Message(sender: (model?.user)!, content: textField.text!)

            do {
                try model?.realm!.write {
                    model?.practice!.messages.append(message)
                }
            } catch {
                print("realm.write had an error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

The error I get is the standard "found nil when unwrapping an optional value" at the line "cell.messageLeading.isActive = false"

Edit: It also happens when I scroll and the cells get dequeued for reuse -- when they try to reappear I get the same error. So its not the sendButtonPressed function. It's something with anytime a cell loads AFTER the initial load.

Any help?

The xib in question, for reference: 
[image: The xib in question, for reference:]

Solution:

Constraint outlets are weird. I couldn't get them to not be nil or work at all. So I switched methods.

Instead I put my message into a stack view and them in my cellForRowAt I simple switch the alignment from trailing to leading like this.

It's a more elegant solution anyway.

```
if (currentMessage?.sender?.firebase_uid == model?.user?.firebase_uid) {
            cell.nonUserLabel.isHidden = true
            cell.userLabel.isHidden = false
            cell.messageStackView.alignment = .trailing
            cell.userLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "\((currentMessage?.sender?.name)!)", attributes:
            [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue])
        } else {
            cell.nonUserLabel.isHidden = false
            cell.userLabel.isHidden = true
            cell.messageStackView.alignment = .leading
            cell.nonUserLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "\((currentMessage?.sender?.name)!)", attributes:
            [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue])
        }
```

Comment: When you set isActive fals to the constrain variable which is weak its removed from memory. Try not using weak before the var in outlet of constraints.

Comment: You should really narrow down what is nil. Is it the cell or the property? Add a few statements to check `guard let cell = cell else { print("cell was nil") return }` etc to determine what was nil.

Comment: This article sums up the problem quite nicely: https://indiestack.com/2016/03/constraint-activation/